# How can I tell when the iPhone is actively using GPS versus only using region monitoring?

Tags: ios, iphone, gps

I run Google Latitude on an iPhone 4 with background updates turned on.  How can I distinguish between when it's actively grabbing the location vs when it's using region monitoring to wait for the phone to move?  As far as I can tell, both icons look the same in the status bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Settings --> Location Services each application that uses location services is listed.  In that list any apps that are *currently* using locations services or have used location services in the last 24 hours includes a little arrow icon.

The icons differ based on whether they are currently or recently used location services, and if currently then whether it's a geofence or regular updates.

The icons and description for each icon are included in that settings panel.

[image: Location services panel showing apps that use location service, including google maps with an arrow next to it, indicating recent use of location services]

[image: Description of each icon in the location services panel]